# Django Web/Dev On same Unix Server

Tags: django

I'm looking at a couple of MVC/MVT frameworks for a new server I'm getting at work (Unix, not sure of the flavor yet).   I'm heavily leaning towards Django as well as Laravel.

What I'm having trouble figuring out right now, is how Django would be setup, or would work, if I need a separation between **web** and **dev** environments.  I'm only getting one server for this.   The other problem I'm trying to figure out is the difficulty in only having 1 database (going with PostgreSQL).  I mean when you're using migrations, how difficult is it to control the db names being different (db names like "test_prod_v1" and "test_dev_v1").

1. How to only have two sub-folders in the htdocs:  **web** and **dev**, and how hard is it to deal with a setup like that?
2. With migrations (etc) how to deal with needing a Web and Dev version of each database?

I need to make a decision next week so I'm just looking for some advice or keyword/concepts to read up on over the weekend (weekend reading pointers).  Thanks for any help or advice.   In setting up a new web server, this is my biggest problem by far in making a framework decision.

Comment: I'm reading non-stop.  Looks like with Postgress you can fairly easily setup multiple db instances assigned to different ports.  So, I could have a totally separate Web and Dev Postgress database on the same server.  That would just take the db problem down to having the db environment defined globally in Django so that it knows which DB instance to used based on if the user is at the /web/ or /dev/ environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your server configurations and situation. But regardless, Django has made it easy to separate the development and production environment.
Django has a file called `settings.py` which contains the variables needed to run the app. All you need to do is set a environment variable when you are on the dev mode and an `if` statement in your `settings.py` to switch between settings. 
Django also comes with a `sqlite3` database as default. What I do personally is to use the `sqlite3` for dev and `postgres` for the production.
To do this, you can follow these steps:

1. Set an environment variable whenever you are on the dev mode, like `DJANGO_DEV="True"`
2. in your regular `settings.py` add all the variables of your production environment such as:

   ```
   DEBUG = False
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'HOST': os.environ['DB_HOST'],
       'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT'],
       'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
       'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
       'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
       }
   }
   ```
3. create another settings file called `settings_dev.py` next to the original settings file and add the configuration for your development environment such as

   ```
   DEBUG = True
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
           'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
       }
   }
   # or whatever that suits you
   ```
4. Then at the end of original `settings.py` add the following:

   ```
   if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEV') is not None:
       from .settings_dev import *
   # This will check if you are on the dev mode and if yes, will replace all the dev configurations with production configurations.
   ```